# Entering Meta Tags to header.php basing on PHP/JS rul

Tags: php, meta

I need to add meta lines to the header.php only where the page url contains /200/

We are currently using this rule:

```
<?php if($page == 200) { ?>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
<?php } ?>
```

> Error log gives an error for this patch: [Tue Mar 12 13:13:15.070693
>   2019] [:error] [pid 28413] [client 127.0.0.1:29570] PHP Notice: 
>   Undefined variable: page in
>   /nas/content/live/parentsdome1/wp-content/themes/voice/header.php on
>   line 27

I have a local JS parameter called page_number

Can I use that somehow instead?

Other ideas on how to 'query' the string to see if it contains "/200/"?

Many thanks!

Comment: how did you try to set `$page` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it only with PHP.

First [get the current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php), then check if [it contains a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word).

```
<?php
    $page = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on'
        ? "https"
        : "http")
        . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    if (strpos($page, '/200/') !== false):
?>

<!-- <meta> -->

<?php
    endif;
?>
```